# Dark background overflows rounded button corners in CSS

Tags: css

The problem is when I set black button background, white color, white 4px border and then `border-radius` say 5px the black pieces appear in the corners of the button. It happens with `<input>` and `<button>` elements. `<div>` tags don't suffer from it.
Is it normal and does somebody know how it could be fixed?

[image]

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mortalis/pen/mpROpg)

HTML:

```
<div id=a>
    <div id=b>Button</div>
    <br>
    <input id="but1" type="button" value="Button" />
    <button id="but2">Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#a {
    background:rgb(255, 250, 204);
    width:200px;
    height:120px;
    padding:10px;
}
div#b {
    border: 4px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
    width: 70px;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
#but1 {
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
    width: 70px;
    color:white;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
#but2 {
    border: 4px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    background: black;
    width: 70px;
    color:white;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: if you don't know where these properties are set you're probably inheriting the styles from somewhere else (and this is one of the main problems in CSS)

Comment: What version of browser you're using. It's fine on Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 m.

Comment: I'm getting this effect on Mozilla 32.0.3 and IE11 though. I guess it's the way browsers render css border-radiuses.

Comment: My browser if Firefox 35

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of browsers's bug, to avoid that you need to use background-clip, like so:

```
    #but1 {
       padding: 5px;
       width: 70px;
       background: black;
       color:white;
       border: 5px solid yellow; 
       border-radius: 5px;

       /* Prevent background color leak outs */
       -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
       -moz-background-clip:    padding; 
       background-clip:padding-box;
    }
```

This is described [here](http://tumble.sneak.co.nz/post/928998513/fixing-the-background-bleed) and [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/)

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer, [robjez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293518/robjez).
Recently I've found almost the same solution. I used `padding-box` for the `background-clip` but with the `background-color` instead of `background`. Cause with the `background` property it only works when the `background-clip` is in the end of the rule. I guess it's because of the cascading inside CSS rules. And if I use `background-color` it works with any order of properties.

```
#but1 {    
    padding: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    border-radius: 5px; 

    color:white;
    background-clip:padding-box;
    background-color: black;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mortalis/pen/ZvLBKL)

[image: Image_1.png]